# Javascript Help - using function from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy

EDIT: I want to access the script on my server (www.example.com/serversidecode.js)
So,that when I call the function host_ss2 it returns the value,which will then be used in my javascript application.

```
//My javascript file stored on the server (www.example.com/serversidecode.js)

    ///SERVER SIDE///
    function host_ss2() { return '1011575268'; }
    function host_ss3() { return '3750'; }
```

However, I want to get the return values but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I am totally stumped.I want to get the return values from my server.

Is there any way to execute the JavaScript on the server and retrieve the return values.

```
var proxySetting = {

    'http_host'  : 'server side return value ss2',
    'http_port'  : 'server side return value ss3',
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Server side language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a web program that lives on your server. Find yourself a web framework and learn how to use it. Learn how to handle an HTTP GET request using your framework - you want to set up your server (configure the framework) so that the GET request invokes your function. Then, on the client (browser) side, you need to learn how to use AJAX to submit a GET request to your server program, receive the response, and process or display it.

you might try geddy since you're using javascript (and, I assume, node.js). http://geddyjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I was wondering whether you know any web frameworks that would help me out or be better suited to what I need.